# Opening a csv file to excel doesnot show special character

Tags: ios, objective-c, export-to-csv

I have exported some data from an iOS app to csv, The csv contains special characters (French Characters) so its not opening properly in Excel.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Tell Excel to use the proper file encoding when you open the file. This isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the file as a CSV in Excel
2. Open Notepad ++
3. In Notepad ++ , select "Encoding > Convert to UTF-8"
4. Save the file as a .txt file
5. Save the .txt file to .csv file
6. Upload your file and you should be
   all good